# Retrieving Owner properties from apex query

Tags: apex, soql, owner

I can query something like `select myCustomField, Owner.Name from myCustomObject`, and get the owner's name in the results, which works as expected in a soql query.

However, when I execute this in Apex, it returns a `List<myCustomObject>`, which does not contain a property for Owner.Name, so the owner value is lost.

I did notice that it does return the OwnerID.  Is there any way to return the actual result of this query in Apex, including the Owner information?

Comment: You should be able to access owner name by List[0].Owner.Name, it doesn't returns lookup object's field by default.

Comment: @DougOler, is that my ans solves your issue then please accept so that other can find this useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOQL query returns owner information and you can retrieve owner information from this list like this way:

```
List<Dealer__c> lstDealer = [SELECT Dealer_Number__c, Name, OwnerId, Owner.Name, owner.type FROM Dealer__c];

if(!lstDealer.isEmpty())
{
    System.debug('owner name=' + lstDealer[0].Owner.Name );
    System.debug('owner type=' + lstDealer[0].Owner.Type);
    System.debug('ownerId=' + lstDealer[0].Owner.Id);
}
```